# I want to transform one input json to desired format using jolt

Tags: json, jolt

My Input json

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "uniqueId": "100",
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true,
      "definition": false,
      "description": "is bundled or not",
      "password": false,
      "name": "isBundled",
      "value": "true",
      "defaultValue": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "immutable": false,
      "isDeclaredListInput": false,
      "getInputProperty": false,
      "empty": false,
      "country": "asdsa"
    }
  ]
}
```

Based on whether defaultValue is present or not we need to have a field inside serviceSpecCharacteristicValue – isDefault – this will be true if value is there otherwise false

This is my spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "properties": {
        "*": {
          "name": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].name",
          "description": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].description",
          "type": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].valueType",
          "required": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].required",
      "defaultValue":"serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].serviceSpecCharacteristicValue[].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Current output

```
{
  "serviceSpecCharacteristic" : [ {
    "name" : "isBundled",
    "description" : "is bundled or not",
    "valueType" : "boolean",
    "required" : true,
    "serviceSpecCharacteristicValue" : [ {
      "value" : "true"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Expected output:-Based on whether defaultValue is present or not we need to have a field inside serviceSpecCharacteristicValue – isDefault – this will be true if value is there otherwise false

```
{
  "serviceSpecCharacteristic" : [ {
    "name" : "isBundled",
    "description" : "is bundled or not",
    "valueType" : "boolean",
    "required" : true,
    "serviceSpecCharacteristicValue" : [ {
      "value" : "true",
      "isdefault":true

    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: This is what you're trying to accomplish -- what specific problem did you encounter while trying to do it? Show the shortest possible segment of your code that lets someone else reproduce the problem you encountered, including any relevant errors in the question itself. By contrast, if you haven't written an code, you probably aren't ready to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I just updated the spec and current ouput. Actually I want to get the output based on the value isdefault in input json. If that value is present I need to show  "isdefault":true .Expected output also mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the defaultValue as false if not exists in the original JSON. Then use shift operation.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "properties": {
        "*": {
          //set defaultValue to false if it does not exists.
          "defaultValue": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "properties": {
        "*": {
          "name": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].name",
          "description": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].description",
          "type": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].valueType",
          "required": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].required",
          "value": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].serviceSpecCharacteristicValue[&1].value",
          "defaultValue": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].serviceSpecCharacteristicValue[&1].isdefault"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit 1 :**

Check if `defaultValue` is false, then set `isdefault` to false, else set `isdefault` to true.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "properties": {
        "*": {
          //set defaultValue to false if it does not exists.
          "defaultValue": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "properties": {
        "*": {
          "name": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].name",
          "description": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].description",
          "type": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].valueType",
          "required": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].required",
          "value": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&1].serviceSpecCharacteristicValue[&1].value",
          "defaultValue": {
            "false": {
              "#false": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&3].isdefault"
            },
            "*": { "#true": "serviceSpecCharacteristic[&3].serviceSpecCharacteristicValue[&3].isdefault" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Jagadeesh. This works but here one use case is not handled. In output serviceSpecCharacteristicValue.isDefault – this should be true if 'defaultValue' is there in input json otherwise false

Comment: The spec will set `isdefault` as false if `defaultValue` does not exists in the input json, else it will set the actual value of the `defaultValue` to the `isdefault`

Comment: Correct.That scenario is working.If the defaultValue does not exists in the input json ,then false will set to output isdefault  . But If any value present in defaultValue of input json then true needs to be set in isdefault

Comment: Edited post - Check if defaultValue is false then set isdefault to false, or set isdefault to true